# HTML5 image in .nav container positioning.

Tags: css, html

I have an image inside the .nav container with background-positioning property set to right that is set under the hover selector to display. It's working almost perfect except I want to move the image over to the left a bit closer to the actual navigation link.  When I try to use inset border thickness or absolute positioning it it either moves the text for the nav link as well (inset border thickness) or its get really messed up when I use absolute positioning for background-position. Any way to move the image without it affecting any things else around it? New to HTML5 and I am using dreamweaver CC and am unfortunately away from my comp at the moment.

Comment: You need to post some code. Also, I wouldn't post a question without being at your computer. The SO community is very responsive and you'll want to be ready to respond to any feedback you get.

Comment: Just trying to get some ideas to try when I get home as it will be very late and SO may not be so responsive then. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `left` property of the background image. In my experience, if you mess with the container then it will mess with everything else. Also, you might have to tinker with the actual image to get it look right.